# How to scroll down/up by one full screen?

Tags: scrolling

Is there a way to scroll down/up by one full screen? My keyboard doesn't have special purpose keys for this function.

In other words, is there a single command that is equivalent to the following sequence (for scrolling one screen down):

1. `C-u -1 M-x move-to-window-line`
2. `C-u 1 M-x recenter`

After this sequence, point is positioned at the top left corner of the window, but it's OK with me (even preferrable) if the scrolling leaves point at the same position relative to the window.

Comment: `window.c` contains the following default bindings:  `C-v` for scroll-up-command, `M-v` for scroll-down-command, and `M-C-v` for scroll-other-window.  There is a popular minor-mode called `centered-cursor-mode` that you may wish to check out.  If you have not already done so, check-out the doc-strings for `scroll-up` and `scroll-down` to see the available options -- i.e., `C-h f` aka `M-x describe-function`.  And, you can always create your own function that does a combination of a few things or sets certain arguments to your liking.

Comment: See also [`(emacs) Scrolling`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html), [`(emacs) Recentering`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html) and [`(emacs) Auto Scrolling`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Scrolling.html).